# Communicating between an HttpServlet and the client side of a GWT application

Tags: gwt, servlets

I have a simple GWT application that consists of a FormPanel that contains a single FileUpload field. The action on this form is to send it to GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "process", which web.xml in turn tells GWT is the FileProcessServlet.

FileProcessServlet is a class that I made that extends HttpServlet and overrides doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) to parse the uploaded file and turn it into a Base64 string using Base64Utils. Now, I would like to pass the client side a single string that is the Base64 encoding of the file just sent it.

For the life of me, I just cannot figure out how to do this. The GWT documentation on [Communicating with the Server](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/clientserver.html) doesn't say anything about receiving information back from a FormPanel.submit(). There is no callback function associated with such a request, as is the case with GWT RPC. At the same time, I need to use a servlet, since I want to parse a file, and that can't be done by the client. Any suggestions?

~~~~

PS: One option is that I can write directly to the html page from the servlet using java.io's PrintWriter (as [this](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-First-Servlets.html) suggests). This may present a kind of solution where I store the Base64 string in a div with a special ID and then use DOM to get this content on the client end. However, I have not yet gotten PrintWriter to cooperate with me. Anytime I use it, with varying content types and character encodings, I still see nothing printed on the page. What I currently have attempting to print this out is:

```
        String base64 = Base64Utils.toBase64(file);
        resp.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.print(base64);
        out.flush(); out.close();
```

But nothing comes out. The debugger has confirmed that the string base64 is not null nor empty on the penultimate line. Any help on this related front would also be appreciated. Nonetheless, I sincerely hope there is a better way.

Comment: How do you integrate the servlet into your page?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
form.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler() {
      public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
        // When the form submission is successfully completed, this event is
        // fired. Assuming the service returned a response of type text/html,
        // we can get the result text here (see the FormPanel documentation for
        // further explanation).
        Window.alert(event.getResults());
      }
    });
```

Whatever you write out from the servlet, will be in the event.getResults(), in your case the base64 String

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for. And it was right there in the FormPanel documentation!

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not 100% sure if your problem is on client or server side.

For the client:

```
formPanel.setAction("/[urlMappingOfYourServlet]");
formPanel.setEncoding(FormPanel.[CORRECT_ENCODING]);
formPanel.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
```

And to start the submission:
`formPanel.submit();`

Don't forget the mapping of your servlet in your web.xml. E.g.:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>nameOfYourServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>your.package.server.YourServletClass</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>nameOfYourServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/urlMappingOfYourServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

On the server side you get the parsed data:

```
String data = request.getParameter("[NameOfYourFormPanelItem]");
```

You could use a `javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream` instead of PrintWriter.

```
    ServletOutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
    out.write(base64);
    out.flush();
```

Another possibility is to use a `RequestBuilder` on the client side:

```
RequestBuilder requestBuilder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, "/urlMappingOfYourServlet");
requestBuilder.sendRequest(someData, new RequestCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponseReceived(Request request,
                            Response response) {
                        // ToDo: Get your String here
            response.getText();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                        // ToDo
                    }
                });
```